# Proving if $\gcd(c,m)=1$ then $\{x\in \Bbb Z \mid ax\equiv b \pmod m\} =\{x\in \Bbb Z \mid cax\equiv cb \pmod m\}$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Okay so I'm confused on how to approach this question.

> If $\gcd(c,m)=1$, then $S=T$ where $S=\{x\in \Bbb Z \mid  ax\equiv b \pmod m\}$ and $T=\{x\in \Bbb Z \mid cax\equiv cb \pmod m\}$.

I know that since $c$ and $m$ are coprime, then there exists two integers $y$ and $z$ such that $cy+mz=1$. Also, I know that to prove $S = T$, I need to show that $S\subseteq T$ and $T\subseteq S$.

But I'm stuck here and don't know how to proceed. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ ax\equiv b\,\overset{\large {\rm times}\ c}\Rightarrow\,cax\equiv cb.\,$ Conversely, by Bezout, $\,\gcd(c,m) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, c^{-1}\,$ exists, thus the opposite direction follows by multiplying $\ cax\equiv cb\,$ by $\,c^{-1}$ to cancel $\,c.$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally, scaling an equation by a unit (invertible) yields an equivalent equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the mentioned identity of Bezout, $y$ is a multiplicative inverse of $c$, modulo $m$.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth stating and proving Bezut here. Bezuts lemma says that if $(a,b)=1$, then $\exists x,y$ st $ax+by=1$. To prove this, consider the set $S:=\{d>0|\exists x,y,ax+by=d\}$. Let $d_0$ be the minimal element of this set and use the division algorithm on $a$ and $d_0$ to find out that $d_0|a$ (Specifically, the remainder is of the form of elements of $S$ but is smaller than the least element of $S$, so the remainder is zero). Then repeat with $b$ and conclude $d_0=1$